# How can I use a photo in Google-Drive in a text message using Message+?

Tags: google-drive

I have a photo in Google-Drive that I would like to include in a text message using Message+. How do I do that?
If I have to transfer the photo to Google photos, how do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and a brief description of the official help docs that you have reviewed so far.

Answer (score -2):

With Android using Google Drive App:

1. Navigate to the photo
2. Select SHARE and change WHO HAS ACCESS to ANYONE WITH THE LINK
3. Copy the Link and paste it into any messaging application or email text

I imagine it is a similar process with Google Drive App in IOS.

https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-share-files-on-google-drive